# Editable CRUD Table with Flask/Python & MySQL

Tags: jquery, python, mysql

I'm trying to implement an editable table with CRUD operations using Python Flask.
Basically every tutorial I found uses PHP.

I saw two tables that I liked:

[Patternfly In Line Editing for Table View](http://www.patternfly.org/pattern-library/forms-and-controls/inline-edit/)

[jQuery Tabledit Example #6](https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/#examples)

I already have the Python code, that connects to my database:

```
def export_ledger():
    cnx = mariadb.connect(  user=cfg.db['user'],
                            password=cfg.db['pwd'],
                            database=cfg.db['baseteste']
                            )
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    query = """
            SELECT ID, data, credito, debito, descricao, valor
            FROM ledger_teste
            ORDER BY data DESC
            """

    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    desc = cursor.description
    cnx.close()

    ledger_completo = [dict(itertools.izip([col[0] for col in desc], row)) 
        for row in rows]

    return json.dumps(ledger_completo)
```

But I still need to write the code to edit shown entries, and to delete entries.

I tried Ajax connection with the following JavaScript code inside my HTML with no success:

```
$('#general_ledger').Tabledit({
        $.ajax({
            url: 'export_ledger',
            method: 'GET'
        }).done(function(data){
            $('tbody').html(data)
            tableData()
        })
    }
```

My question is: how to make the JSON that results from this Python code feed the table, and how to add functions to edit and delete entries?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hi, I see that nobody answered your question. I was curious if you found the solution to your question? Cause I am looking for something similiar but I only find php related stuff.

Comment: Hey. It's been a while, but I got it working after quite a long time with:     journal = [list(i) for i in rows]
    journal = [[s.encode('ascii', 'ignore') for s in i] for i in journal]
    return render_template('journal.html', journal=journal) (journal is JSON object). And them on JS: <script type="text/javascript">
    
var journal = {{ journal|safe }}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#journal_table').DataTable({
        data: journal,
        columns: [{ title: "ID" },{ title: "Date" },
{ title: "Credit" },
{ title: "Debit" },
{ title: "Value" }]});});
</script>

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, but basically in flask you pass the variable on the "render_template" function, and then you get the variable with JS using the {{ variable|safe }} code. It also depends a lot on which table your are using. This worked with DataTable, each plugin is different.

Comment: could a working answer be posted? I'm staring at this trying to work out how you managed to get this to work

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a working answer. But the main logic is to pass the variable to JS through Flask's render_template. And then you'll have an array and the challenge will be on JS front end side. Anyways, I ended up using Jinja template engine.